# STA not recognized in Slim (FitNesse)

Tags: fitnesse, sta, fitnesse-slim

I wrote a custom table class for Slim that lets users write commands that are used to run automated tests. All commands are now working, except for one that relies on a certain call that has to be made in an STA thread. I was able to solve this issue in Fit by adding 
 STA 
to the suiteConfig file. However, it looks like adding that to the Slim config does not work. This is the code I have:

`!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -c C:\..\Slim\slim.config.xml}

!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\..\Slim\Runner.exe}`

`<suiteConfig>

    <ApplicationUnderTest>

        <AddAssembly>C:\..\Slim\fit.dll</AddAssembly>

        <AddAssembly>C:\..\Slim\fitSharp.dll</AddAssembly>

    </ApplicationUnderTest>

    <Settings>

                <ApartmentState>STA</ApartmentState>

        <Runner>fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner</Runner>

    </Settings>

    <FileExclusions>

        <Add>^\.svn$</Add>

    </FileExclusions>

</suiteConfig>`

Would there be any reason why STA mode has a different effect in Fit than in Slim? Is there anything I need to modify in the command pattern or config file? Any help would be much appreciated!

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Will be fixed in next release http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues#issue/54